# Excel Functions and Formula: Return two answers in match function

Tags: excel

Please refer on below table. I need a formula/function that will display the Customer Name/s automatically. Cheapest rates column is the number result from columns John, Mark, Anthon, Venus and Carla. Let me know if you need more clarifications.

```
+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------------+-----------------+
| John  | Mark  | Anthon | Venus | Carla | Cheapest Rates | Customer Name/s |
+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------------+-----------------+
| Candy | Candy | Candy  | Candy | Candy | Candy          |                 |
+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------------+-----------------+
| 80    | 70    | 70     | 100   | 90    | 70             | Mark/Anthon     |
+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------------+-----------------+
|       | 30    |        | 30    | 50    | 30             | Mark/Venus      |
+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------------+-----------------+
| 130   | 100   | 50     | 150   | 50    | 50             | Anthon/Carla    |
+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+----------------+-----------------+
```

thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this yourself? Show us what you have done and specifically where you are stuck.

Comment: what you want can't be done using excel built in function without a helper column (concatenating all matches in one cell). It is however possible using a UDF.

Answer (score 0):

here's using formula with helper columns:

**Helper column Formula:**

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$E$1,1,SMALL(IF($A2:$E2=MIN($A2:$E2),COLUMN($A2:$E2),20000),COLUMN(B$1))),"")` entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Entered in `F2` then drag and fill the remaining cells in the helper column.

**Screen Shot(helper):**
[image: Helper column formula]

**Final Column Formula:**

`=CONCATENATE(IF(F2<>"",IF(G2<>"",F2&"/",F2),""),IF(G2<>"",IF(H2<>"",G2&"/",G2),""),IF(H2<>"",IF(I2<>"",H2&"/",H2),""),IF(I2<>"",IF(J2<>"",I2&"/",I2),""),IF(J2<>"",J2,""))` entered as normal formula.

**Screen Shot(final):**
[image: final column]

You can hide the helper columns for aesthetic.

**Update1:**

Here's the UDF:
Warning: This only works in data structured like your example.
To make this work with any range orientation and format, you have to add a lot of conditions.

```
Function MINPLUS(target_value As Range, return_value As Range, Optional delimiter As Variant) As String

Dim min As Long, cel As Range

min = Application.WorksheetFunction.min(target_value)

If IsMissing(delimiter) Then delimiter = ","

For Each cel In target_value
    If cel.Value2 = min Then
        If MINPLUS = "" Then
            MINPLUS = return_value(1, cel.Column)
        Else
            MINPLUS = MINPLUS & delimiter & return_value(1, cel.Column)
        End If
    End If
Next

End Function
```

Hope this helps you a bit.